# Flutter SQFlite - type bool is not a subtype of type int in type cast

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqflite

I am a complete flutter and sqflite beginner. I am trying to make my calendar events persist over app restarts so I am implementing an SQFlite database. However, I keep running into this error and have no idea what is causing it. I tried to debug this with Phind, a programming AI, but to no avail.

Error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
E/flutter ( 6428): #0      EventHandler.fromJson
event_info_model.dart:57
E/flutter ( 6428): #1      EventsDatabase.readAllEvents.<anonymous closure>
events_database.dart:95
E/flutter ( 6428): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)
E/flutter ( 6428): #3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:344:26)
E/flutter ( 6428): #4      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
E/flutter ( 6428): #5      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
E/flutter ( 6428): #6      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:47:28)
E/flutter ( 6428): #7      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:214:7)
E/flutter ( 6428): #8      EventsDatabase.readAllEvents
events_database.dart:96
E/flutter ( 6428): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6428): #9      _CalendarViewPageState.refreshEvents
calendar_view_page.dart:54
E/flutter ( 6428): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Database code:

```dart
        // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_declarations
        
        import 'dart:async';
        import 'package:effici/models/event_info_model.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter_neat_and_clean_calendar/flutter_neat_and_clean_calendar.dart';
        // ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
        import 'package:path/path.dart';
        import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
        
        class EventsDatabase {
          static final EventsDatabase instance = EventsDatabase._init();
        
          static Database? _database;
        
          EventsDatabase._init();
        
          Future<Database> get database async {
            debugPrint("Getting database...");
            if (_database != null) return _database!;
        
            _database = await _initDB('events.db');
            return _database!;
          }
        
          Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
            final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
            final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
            debugPrint("Database initialized. It is present at: $dbPath");
            return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
          }
        
          Future _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
            final textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
            final integerType = 'INTEGER NOT NULL';
            final booleanType = 'INTEGER DEFAULT 0';
        
            await db.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE $eventsTable
            (
              'summary' $textType,
              'description' $textType,
              'startTime' $integerType,
              'endTime' $integerType,
              'isAllDay' $booleanType
            )
            ''');
          }
        
          Future<void> create(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) async {
            debugPrint("The create function has been entered.");
            final db = await instance.database;
        
            await db.insert(eventsTable, EventHandler().toJson(event));
            debugPrint(EventsDatabase.instance.toString());
            debugPrint("The create function has been exited.");
          }
        
          Future<NeatCleanCalendarEvent?> readEvent(
              String summary, DateTime startTime) async {
            final db = await instance.database;
        
            final maps = await db.query(
              eventsTable,
              columns: EventFields.values,
              where: 'summary = ? AND startTime = ?',
              whereArgs: [summary, startTime],
            );
        
            if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
              final map = maps.first;
              final modifiedMap = Map<String, Object?>.from(map);
              modifiedMap['isAllDay'] =
                  (map['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false); // Convert to boolean
              return EventHandler.fromJson(modifiedMap);
            } else {
              return null; // Return null if no matching event is found
            }
          }
        
          Future<List<NeatCleanCalendarEvent>> readAllEvents() async {
            final db = await instance.database;
        
            final orderBy = 'startTime ASC';
        
            final result = await db.query(
              eventsTable,
              orderBy: orderBy,
            );
        
            return result.map((json) {
              final modifiedJson = Map<String, Object?>.from(json);
              modifiedJson['isAllDay'] =
                  (json['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false); // Convert to boolean
              return EventHandler.fromJson(modifiedJson);
            }).toList();
          }
        
          Future<int> update(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) async {
            debugPrint("The update function has been entered.");
            final db = await instance.database;
        
            return db.update(
              eventsTable,
              EventHandler().toJson(event),
              where: 'summary = ? AND startTime = ?',
              whereArgs: [event.summary, event.startTime],
            );
          }
        
          Future<int> delete(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) async {
            debugPrint("The delete function has been entered.");
            final db = await instance.database;
        
            return await db.delete(
              eventsTable,
              where: 'summary = ? AND startTime = ?',
              whereArgs: [event.summary, event.startTime],
            );
          }
        
          Future<void> close() async {
            debugPrint("The close function has been entered.");
            final db = await instance.database;
        
            await db.close();
          }
        }
```

EventHandler class -

```
final String eventsTable = 'events';

class EventFields {
  static final List<String> values = [
    summary,
    description,
    startTime,
    endTime,
    isAllDay
  ];

  static final String summary = 'summary';
  static final String description = 'description';
  static final String startTime = 'startTime';
  static final String endTime = 'endTime';
  static final String isAllDay = 'isAllDay'; // Add this line for the new field
}

class EventHandler {
  Map<String, Object?> toJson(NeatCleanCalendarEvent event) => {
        EventFields.summary: event.summary,
        EventFields.description: event.description,
        EventFields.startTime: event.startTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        EventFields.endTime: event.endTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        EventFields.isAllDay: event.isAllDay ? 1 : 0, // Convert to integer
      };

  static NeatCleanCalendarEvent fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
        json[EventFields.summary] as String,
        description: json[EventFields.description] as String,
        startTime: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            json[EventFields.startTime] as int),
        endTime: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            json[EventFields.endTime] as int),
        isAllDay:
            (json[EventFields.isAllDay] as int) == 1, // Convert to boolean
      );
}
```

Comment: You have a problem here: `return EventHandler.fromJson(modifiedMap);` but you don't show that code. Please also explain the reason for this: `map['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Richard! I have edited my question include the code for the EventHandler class and its methods. The reason I have that code is to make the 'isAllDay' variable default to false in the map if it is null. Hope that helps!

Comment: Forgot to add this in my previous response, but what exactly is wrong about the code? Just so I can use it not make this mistake in the future. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
          modifiedMap['isAllDay'] =
              (map['isAllDay'] == 1 ? true : false); // Convert to boolean
```

you have made the dynamic a `bool`, but then you immediately try to cast it as an `int` here:

```
    isAllDay:
        (json[EventFields.isAllDay] as int) == 1, // Convert to boolean
```

Simply remove the whole `modifiedMap` stuff, and try:

```
    return EventHandler.fromJson(map);
```